# sending email from godaddy account using C#

Tags: c#, .net, email

I'm trying to send and email from a C# application running on the desktop. Does anyone see any particular reason why this would error and time out, as a result never sending the email. I've looked around online and haven't been able to find a solution which actually works when doing this.

I do however had a php mail which runs directly off the godaddy server which sends emails. So i know the server isn't the problem. The php version doesn't require a password.

Here is the code.

```
SmtpClient ss = new SmtpClient();
            try
            {
                ss.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
                ss.Port = 25;
                ss.Timeout = 10000;
                ss.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                ss.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                ss.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("daemon@johntest.com", "####");

                MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage("daemon@johntest.com", "testingJohn@gmail.com", "testing email", "my body");
                mailMsg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
                ss.Send(mailMsg);

                Console.WriteLine("Sent email");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in System.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Include the error messages from your exceptions please.

Comment: you initial problem looks to be in the `ss.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("daemon@johntest.com", "####");` usually it's the network username not the email address tested the method below with the code and works fine for me.. fails when I use it from my local with my network email address..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a method like this to test either from your local mailhost then try it with godaddy

```
public static void SendEmail(string subject, string body)
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient(yourEmailHost, 25)) //"relay-hosting.secureserver.net"
    using (var message = new MailMessage()
    {
        From = new MailAddress(utilities.FromEmail),
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    })
    {
        message.To.Add(address);
        //client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        //client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("nerwork UserName", "Network Password");
        client.Send(message);
    };
}
```

Comment: `("network UserName", "Network Password")` What does that translate to on godaddy? Is that my login?

Comment: you need to consult with godaddy if it is then replace username with your godaddy email and password with your godaddy account password